# Find Overlapping Trajectories

Tags: mongodb, gis, geospatial

Consider the following case : [image]

I have stored trips/trajectories in mongodb as `LineString` and index is `2dsphere`.

According to the image provided, `Trip 1` is a trajectory that a user wants to search for and `Trip2-6` are trips that are already stored on mongodb.

Given a maxDistance on $near, Trip1 should be "matched" with Trip 3 and 4 as shown.

However [$geointersects](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) seem to accept a `Polygon or Multipolygon` as $geometry type and [$near](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) seem to accept only `Point`.

Is there any **time efficient** way to implement the following scenario with mongo queries?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT** : I changed geometry to `Polygon`, as  Alex Blex said.

Visualisation of data (Trip 1 is the search Trip, Trip2-3 are stored in db)

[image: Visualisation of Trips]

So we have the following documents stored on mongo:

*Trip2*

```
  tripData: Object
 {
   type: Polygon
   coordinates: [ 
      [ [8,2] , [7,3] , [7,4], [8,2] ] 
   ]
 }
```

*Trip3*

```
  tripData: Object
 {
   type: Polygon
   coordinates: [ 
      [ [3,1], [4,1], [4,1.9999], [3,1] ] 
   ]
 }
```

*Trip 1 is the trip we search for*

```
  tripData: Object
 {
   type: Polygon
   coordinates: [ 
      [ [2,2] , [1,4] , [3,5] , [4,2] , [2,2] ] 
   ]
 }
```

The query i run is the following :

```
 db.trips.find({ tripData: { $geoIntersects : { $geometry : trip1 } } } )
```

Nothing is returned from this query as expected, because trips do not intersect as you can see in the Visualisation. How can i modify the query in order to match Trip1 with Trip3 using $near operator ?

Comment: How do you store the trips? If it is just a line, you can do a simple math to calculate intersection.

Comment: I store trips as LineString (that means array of coordinates), but i would like to take advantage of the 2dsphere index and have the efficiency mongo provides on handling geospatial data. 

Moreover, i think doing the maths, will be time consuming as i have to compare each point of Trip 1 with every other point of other trips in worst case.

Comment: By "math" I mean converting target `Trip 1` to poly by adding `near` value to    coordinates. Basically to geointersect the lime shape you have drawn. It would be simpler to answer with code, if you provide some data.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for your time, i've edited the question.

Comment: You don't like test driven approach, do you =) I expected to see 2 documents and 1 query, with such coordinates that you know that only 1 document should be returned, e.g. `Trip 4`, and `Trip 6` documents, and `Trip 1` query  with `near` value.

Comment: @AlexBlex Well, i consider myself to be cooperative, you just did not clarify what "data" you expected to see.Now that everything is clear, I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'd wish I could explain things more clearly =( I suggested to convert to polygon a single line `Trip1` - the one that is used in the query. I have added more explanations and examples how to convert line to poly in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geoIntersects` requires polygons or multipolygons **in the query**, i.e. Trip1 in the question. Trip2-6 are `LineString` stored in the documents, which is perfectly fine. So the only extra thing to do is to convert Trip1 to polygon using offset, shown as lime `near` in the question.

Let's consider straight line first. The function to convert line `[[x1,y1][x2,y2]]` to polygon with offset `d` can be as simple as:

```
function LineToPolyWithFalsePositive(line, d) {
    var teta = Math.atan2(line[1][0] - line[0][0], line[1][1] - line[0][1]);
    var s = Math.sin(teta);
    var c = Math.cos(teta);
    return [
        [line[0][0] - d*s - d*c, line[0][1] - d*c + d*s], 
        [line[1][0] + d*s - d*c, line[1][1] + d*c + d*s], 
        [line[1][0] + d*s + d*c, line[1][1] + d*c - d*s], 
        [line[0][0] - d*s + d*c, line[0][1] - d*c - d*s]
    ];
}
```

or

```
function LineToPolyWithFalseNegative(line, d) {
    var teta = Math.atan2(line[1][0] - line[0][0], line[1][1] - line[0][1]);
    var s = Math.sin(teta);
    var c = Math.cos(teta);
    return [
        [line[0][0] - d*s, line[0][1] - d*c], 
        [line[0][0] - d*c, line[0][1] + d*s], 
        [line[1][0] - d*c, line[1][1] + d*s], 
        [line[1][0] + d*s, line[1][1] + d*c], 
        [line[1][0] + d*c, line[1][1] - d*s], 
        [line[0][0] + d*c, line[0][1] - d*s]
    ];
}
```

Which produce lime polygons as on the image below:

[image]

The returned value can be used in `geoIntersects` query against documents with `LineString` locations.

The problematic areas highlighted with red. The first poly covers distance more than `d` on edge cases, and the second poly covers less distance than `d` in the same edge cases.

If it was the only problem, I would go with false negative approach and run 2 more `near` queries for Points `[x1,y1]` and `[x2,y2]` to check if there are any missed documents in the highlighted areas.

If Trip1 is a complex `LineString`, there are much more calculations need to be done to convert it to polygon. See the image:

[image]

Apart from the edge cases for first and last point, there are similar problems for start and end of each segment. Basically you will need to calculate an angle between each segment to workout corresponded vertices of the polygon. Still doable thou. In the false-negative version of the polygon, the vertices circled with red should be cut, again considering the angle between segments.

If the Trip1 line in the query have many segments, it may be quite expensive, as you will need to run `near` query for each vertex + 2 for terminal points.

As a pragmatic approach, if it **is** acceptable, the false-positive version may work quite fast, as it is a single query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. However this approach seems nice, i implemented Routeboxer instead.